# Looking for example of test cases under ipv4 and ipv6

Tags: manual-testing

I'm looking for the test scenarios that I can perform under ipv4 and ipv6 netowrk

Ideally software must pass under next network environment:

- both IPv4 and IPv6?
- Ipv4
- Ipv6

is there any negative test scenarios I can add/excute?

Comment: What is your objective here? Can you give us more context for what you are doing and trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between IPv4 and IPv6 is the octet usage for connectivity.  If you are doing "application" testing, then it's really ensuring that you are connected via an IPv6 connection and testing and connecting via an IPv4 connection and testing.  Ensure the results are the same and you have ensured that the application is working with both.

If you need something more specific related to the DNS/IP specifics/etc... then please put that in the question for a more specific answer.  Otherwise it's really just a connectivity test and the rest is the same.